# What is the terminology for a pure function that produces a sequence from a single input called?

Tags: functional-programming

I understand that a map function will return an array result for an array input, a reduce function will return a single result for an array input, and a filter will return an array result for an array input. I also understand that a generator function is not pure because it holds state.

**In functional programming, what is the common generic term for the category of pure functions that processes input element(s) and produces a sequence of elements?**

An example of such a function is one that creates a sequence of elements from a range input.

I know it isn't a 'Generator' function because generators are not considered pure functions.

I know it isn't a 'Mapping' function because it returns more elements in the output sequence than in the input sequence.

I don't think it is a 'Generating' function, but may be wrong. Generating function has a specific meaning in discrete mathematics. In particular, it implies a function that will generate an infinite series, definitely not relevant to this scenario.

Update: There has been some good feedback and discussion, but I'm still not sure I have the answer. Functionally this can be done with reduce or with flatmap. I was wondering if there was a more common term for this behavior; something as ubiquitous as map, reduce and filter are.

Comment: outputs = query(input) :p perhaps 'Resolver'

Comment: "generator" seems fine to me. Just make the state explicit if you need to.

Comment: Agreed with @Bergi that a generator seems fine to me as well.  It might be convenient to view it as a thunk/continuation that evaluates to the next value in the sequence and another thunk that does the same.  E.g. a PRNG could be viewed like this, with each invocation yielding the next value in the series.

Comment: I agree a generator can return a new result with each call. But that makes it inherently not a pure function as it requires a state.

Comment: Have a look at [infinite lists in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#g:17) a language famous for its purity.  Each continuation would always return the same value, so no mutable state, but because each function also returns another continuation/closure/anonymous function it allows you to get the next value.  These are very convenient in lazy languages like Haskell where the values are only evaluated on need, compared to conventional strict languages where the programmer explicitly specifies the evaluation order.

Comment: OCaml's [`Seq` module](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) sounds like a good example of this.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what kind of terminology you pick up. For example, I'm not particularly clear on what you mean by a *Generator* function, but in general, a function that produces a sequence from a single starting point may not need to be stateful.

> a reduce function will return a single result for an array input

Not necessarily. More generally, a *reduce* function may be considered a special case of a *fold*, and while a fold can reduce something 'foldable' (like an array) to a single value, it can also produce itself, as this Haskell example demonstrates:

```
ghci> foldr (:) [] [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

This also suggests that you can implement 'mapping' (i.e. [functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/22/functors) capabilities) using some folds:

```
ghci> foldr ((:) . show . (+) 1) [] [1,2,3]
["2","3","4"]
```

For a lot of 'foldable' structures, the *fold* is equivalent to the data structure's [catamorphism](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/04/29/catamorphisms) (Greek: 'down-shaper'), but for other data structures (e..g [either](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/06/03/either-catamorphism) or [tree](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/06/10/tree-catamorphism)) the catamorphism is a more general concept.

So in general, a *catamorphism* is a pure function that 'walks over' a data structure and produces a potentially more compact value as output.

The dual of a catamorphism is called an *anamorphism* (Greek: 'up-shaper'), or more narrowly *unfold*:

```
ghci> unfoldr (\b -> if b == 0 then Nothing else Just (b, b-1)) 10
[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Because Haskell is lazy, you can use anamorphisms to produce infinite sequences with pure functions. In other languages, you may have to resort to Iterators or something similar to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Given OPs history, I'd assume they're talking about a [javascript generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), hence their references to state

Comment: I don't know what haskall or formal/pure functional programming languages would call it.  But it appears that the behavior I'm describing is very similar to flatMap in some programming languages.

Comment: When I mentioned "Generator" functions, I was referring to functions that return a new value each time you call them.  They are stateful and are NOT the pattern I want to describe because as they are not pure functions.

Comment: @SamMason I see no impure state in the linked docs. It's a deterministic Iterator, essentially equivalent to a lazily evaluated list. In Haskell it would literally just be `['a','b','c']`, since Haskell is lazy by default. It's most likely true that JavaScript's underlying implementation of `yield` involves a state machine, but is that relevant? Ultimately, anything that runs on a computer is impure because it changes values in CPU registers. Shouldn't the question rather be whether or not a function is [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)?

Comment: @MarkSeemann yes, Haskell's lazy semantics mean its lists could use a similar implementation as javascript generators (not sure what implementations use internally).  Javascript let's you write generators with shared mutable state that would be discouraged in Haskell.

Comment: @SamMason True, this is the case for almost any language apart from Haskell, PureScript and a few other exotic languages. Possibly relevant: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/02/24/discerning-and-maintaining-purity

Answer (score 0):

flatMap() appears to be an example of this behavior, for some languages/libraries. Unlike map(), flatmap() can return a different number of items than input.

The lambda function passed to flatmap can return either a single item or an array of items. flatmap will flatten them into a single sequence as a result.  Which, as previously mentioned, can be a different length than the input sequence.

flatmap() seems to be the functional solution for my need, but still wondering if there is general terminology for this type of function.  Something as ubiquitous as Map, Reduce, and Filter functions are.

Comment: Only you know what your requirements are, but `flatmap` is typically another name for [monadic](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/03/28/monads) *bind*. For lists or arrays, it takes as input not a single value, but a list/array, as well as a function. The input can be any list/array: Empty, or with one or more values. Thus, it doesn't fit what you originally asked for: "what is the terminology for the class of pure functions that takes a *single* input and produces a sequence of elements?" (My emphasis)

Comment: True, but a single-element array resulting in a multiple-element array is essentially the same scenario for practical purposes.

Comment: Indeed, and if it works for you, it works for you. You did, however, ask about terminology, and gave an example of producing a sequence from a range. How are you going to do that with `flatmap` (monadic *bind*)?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I updated this to clarify I was providing a functional example, I still don't know if it is the answer.